# How to do a JOIN inside a CASE? Or use a UNION? (SQL)

Tags: sql

I currently have two different queries for a module in an application I just started to support (first programming job). The first query selects all cars where the Engine is in (9,10,11,12,13). The second one gets all cars where the Engine is in (4,44). They both work fine, the only problem is that when they are placed in the same table on the JSP, they don't use the same filter. So basically, all the data for the first query will always come first, and the data for the second query will always come second. If you sort alphabetically, it will sort all of the data from the first query, A-Z, then the data from the second query, A-Z, so you would see something like:

```
A Car with Engine 11
B Car with Engine 9
C Car with Engine 13
D Car with Engine 12
A Car with Engine 44
B Car with Engine 44
C Car with Engine 4
```

So I thought it would probably be best to just do some kind of CASE and JOIN combination and just have one single query. Unfortunately, I am having trouble figuring out the best way to do that. The data is being pulled from views in an Oracle database.  Below are the two queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
P.CAR_ID CAR_ID,
P.TYPE TYPE,
P.LAST_TIME_SERVICED LAST_TIME_SERVICED,
P.SERVICE_TYPE SERVICE_TYPE,
P.PURCHASE_DATE PURCHASE_DATE,
'20'|| SUBSTR (P.MODEL_YEAR, 1, 2)|| ' - '|| '20'|| SUBSTR (P.MODEL_YEAR, 3, 4)          MODEL_YEAR,
P.DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION,
P.ENGINE_TYPE ENGINE_TYPE,
V.MODEL_ID MODEL_ID,
V.POPULAR_NAME POPULAR_NAME,
V.GMC GMC,
V.DISPUTE DISPUTE,
V.ENGINE ENGINE,
'20'|| SUBSTR (V.YEAR, 1, 2)|| ' - '|| '20'|| SUBSTR (V.YEAR, 3, 4) YEAR,
DECODE (V.SUBS, '~', NULL, V.SUBS) SUBS,
V.CONSEC CONSEC,
RFI.CUST_CUST_ID CUST_CUST_ID, 
RFI.SALESMAN SALESMAN
    FROM DEALER.VW_INV_FOR_SALE RFI, DEALER.VW_OLD_SALES P,
    DEALER.VW_NEW_SALES V
        WHERE P.ENGINE_TYPE IN (9,10,11,12,13)
        AND V.MODEL_ID = RFI.MODEL_ID
        AND RFI.MODEL_ID = P.MODEL_ID
        AND V.YEAR >='1011'
        AND V.YEAR = P.MODEL_YEAR
        AND V.ENGINE = P.ENGINE_TYPE
        AND V.SUBS = P.SUBSCRIPT
        AND P.DESCRIPTION != '100% SAFE'
        AND RFI.CUST_CUST_ID IN (SELECT CUST_ID FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUST_ID = ?
            UNION 
            SELECT CUST_ID FROM CUSTOMERS 
            START WITH CUST_CUST_ID = ?
            CONNECT BY PRIOR CUST_ID = CUST_CUST_ID)
```

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT
P.CAR_ID CAR_ID,
P.TYPE TYPE,
P.LAST_TIME_SERVICED LAST_TIME_SERVICED,
P.SERVICE_TYPE SERVICE_TYPE,
P.PURCHASE_DATE PURCHASE_DATE,
'20'|| SUBSTR (P.MODEL_YEAR, 1, 2)|| ' - '|| '20'|| SUBSTR (P.MODEL_YEAR, 3, 4) MODEL_YEAR,
RFI.CUST_CUST_ID CUST_CUST_ID, 
RFI.SALESMAN SALESMAN,
P.DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION,
P.ENGINE_TYPE ENGINE_TYPE,
Q.MODEL_ID MODEL_ID,
Q.POPULAR_NAME POPULAR_NAME,
Q.GMC GMC,
Q.DISPUTE DISPUTE,
Q.ENGINE ENGINE,
'20'|| SUBSTR (Q.YEAR, 1, 2)|| ' - '|| '20'|| SUBSTR (Q.YEAR, 3, 4) YEAR,
DECODE (Q.SUBS, '~', NULL, Q.SUBS) SUBS,
Q.CONSEC CONSEC,
Q.RESULT RESULT
    FROM DEALER.VW_INV_FOR_SALE RFI, DEALER.VW_OLD_SALES P,
    DEALER.VW_ENGINE4_RESULT Q
        WHERE P.ENGINE_TYPE IN (4,44)
        AND Q.MODEL_ID = RFI.MODEL_ID
        AND RFI.MODEL_ID = P.MODEL_ID
        AND Q.YEAR >='1011'
        AND Q.YEAR = P.MODEL_YEAR
        AND Q.ENGINE = P.ENGINE_TYPE
        AND Q.SUBS = P.SUBSCRIPT
        AND P.DESCRIPTION != '100% SAFE'
        AND RFI.CUST_CUST_ID IN (SELECT CUST_ID FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUST_ID = ?
            UNION 
            SELECT CUST_ID FROM CUSTOMERS 
            START WITH CUST_CUST_ID = ?
            CONNECT BY PRIOR CUST_ID = CUST_CUST_ID)
```

Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is really hard to follow ur lengthy queries with the problem mentioned. Can you please simplify ur question with sample query to address only the problem ur facing. i.e. something like i hv 2 tables A and B. I want data from A which are not in B.

Comment: Other than the engine types, how are these queries different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least intrusive way to accomplish this would be to simply UNION both queries, then apply an ORDER BY on the columns to sort by.  The only issue is that a UNION requires all columns in both queries to line up.  Since you have columns in one query that aren't in the other, they have to be substituted with a placeholder (generally NULL).

So something like this:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT
    P.CAR_ID CAR_ID,
    P.TYPE TYPE,
    P.LAST_TIME_SERVICED LAST_TIME_SERVICED,
    P.SERVICE_TYPE SERVICE_TYPE,
    P.PURCHASE_DATE PURCHASE_DATE,
    '20'|| SUBSTR (P.MODEL_YEAR, 1, 2)|| ' - '|| '20'|| SUBSTR (P.MODEL_YEAR, 3, 4) MODEL_YEAR,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    P.DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION,
    P.ENGINE_TYPE ENGINE_TYPE,
    V.MODEL_ID MODEL_ID,
    V.POPULAR_NAME POPULAR_NAME,
    V.GMC GMC,
    V.DISPUTE DISPUTE,
    V.ENGINE ENGINE,
    '20'|| SUBSTR (V.YEAR, 1, 2)|| ' - '|| '20'|| SUBSTR (V.YEAR, 3, 4) YEAR,
    DECODE (V.SUBS, '~', NULL, V.SUBS) SUBS,
    V.CONSEC CONSEC,
    RFI.CUST_CUST_ID CUST_CUST_ID, 
    RFI.SALESMAN SALESMAN
FROM DEALER.VW_INV_FOR_SALE RFI, DEALER.VW_OLD_SALES P,
    DEALER.VW_NEW_SALES V
WHERE P.ENGINE_TYPE IN (9,10,11,12,13)
    AND V.MODEL_ID = RFI.MODEL_ID
    AND RFI.MODEL_ID = P.MODEL_ID
    AND V.YEAR >='1011'
    AND V.YEAR = P.MODEL_YEAR
    AND V.ENGINE = P.ENGINE_TYPE
    AND V.SUBS = P.SUBSCRIPT
    AND P.DESCRIPTION != '100% SAFE'
    AND RFI.CUST_CUST_ID IN (SELECT CUST_ID FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUST_ID = ?
                              UNION 
                             SELECT CUST_ID FROM CUSTOMERS 
                                    START WITH CUST_CUST_ID = ?
                                    CONNECT BY PRIOR CUST_ID = CUST_CUST_ID)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
    P.CAR_ID CAR_ID,
    P.TYPE TYPE,
    P.LAST_TIME_SERVICED LAST_TIME_SERVICED,
    P.SERVICE_TYPE SERVICE_TYPE,
    P.PURCHASE_DATE PURCHASE_DATE,
    '20'|| SUBSTR (P.MODEL_YEAR, 1, 2)|| ' - '|| '20'|| SUBSTR (P.MODEL_YEAR, 3, 4) MODEL_YEAR,
    RFI.CUST_CUST_ID CUST_CUST_ID, 
    RFI.SALESMAN SALESMAN,
    P.DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION,
    P.ENGINE_TYPE ENGINE_TYPE,
    Q.MODEL_ID MODEL_ID,
    Q.POPULAR_NAME POPULAR_NAME,
    Q.GMC GMC,
    Q.DISPUTE DISPUTE,
    Q.ENGINE ENGINE,
    '20'|| SUBSTR (Q.YEAR, 1, 2)|| ' - '|| '20'|| SUBSTR (Q.YEAR, 3, 4) YEAR,
    DECODE (Q.SUBS, '~', NULL, Q.SUBS) SUBS,
    Q.CONSEC CONSEC,
    NULL,   
    Q.RESULT RESULT
FROM DEALER.VW_INV_FOR_SALE RFI, DEALER.VW_OLD_SALES P,
     DEALER.VW_ENGINE4_RESULT Q
WHERE P.ENGINE_TYPE IN (4,44)
    AND Q.MODEL_ID = RFI.MODEL_ID
    AND RFI.MODEL_ID = P.MODEL_ID
    AND Q.YEAR >='1011'
    AND Q.YEAR = P.MODEL_YEAR
    AND Q.ENGINE = P.ENGINE_TYPE
    AND Q.SUBS = P.SUBSCRIPT
    AND P.DESCRIPTION != '100% SAFE'
    AND RFI.CUST_CUST_ID IN (SELECT CUST_ID FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CUST_ID = ?
                              UNION 
                             SELECT CUST_ID FROM CUSTOMERS 
                                    START WITH CUST_CUST_ID = ?
                                    CONNECT BY PRIOR CUST_ID = CUST_CUST_ID) )
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```